# getting 2 different value from the same variable - React custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created two componentes :

component useImgPicker - custom hook:

- responsible to open the camera
- user can take a picture
- save the image url to imgUrl variable
  return:

  - someFunction (function that open the camera and save the url)
  - imgUrl (the state - string)

2. component App - use the custom hook

   - use the custom hook
   - after the user click on the button, diplayImg function activated
   - diplayImg function use the custom hook, and make change to hasTakePicture variable (become true).
   - after hasTakePicture become true -> new `<View>` render with

**the desire:**  the source url inside the `<Img>` will change to the newUrl

**the result:** the value of newUrl inside `<Img>` is the same, but inside `<Text> {newUrl} </Text>`  the newUrl  is change

component ImgPicker  - custom react hook

```
import {useState} from 'react';
const useImgPicker = ()=>{
     const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState(''); //string
      

     const someFunction = ()=>{
         // make chang to imgUrl
          const newUrl = "/some dumi url.png"
         setImgUrl(newUrl);
      }

return{ imgUrl, someFunction  }

}

export default useImgPicker;
```

component App - use the custom hook

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import useImgPicker from './ImgPicker.js'


const App = ()=>{

   const { imgUrl, someFunction  } = useImgPicker ();
  const [hasTakePicture, setHasTakePicture] = useState(false);


const diplayImg = ()=>{
     someFunction();
     setHasTakePicture(true);
     console.log(imgUrl); // here the value of imgUrl is -> ''  empty (default value)

}


    return(
         {hasTakePicture ? (
            <View>
              // inside the 'source' prop of the Image the value of imgUrl-> ''  empty (default value) 
             <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: imgUrl}} resizeMode='contain'/>
           
           {imgUrl}  // -> here the value of imgUrl is -> newUrl
         </View>
           
        ) :
        (
          <View></View>
        )
      }
     
      <Button title="Take Picture" onPress = {diplayImg } >
    )

}
```

Comment: Please be aware that custom react hooks must put `use` at the beginning of their name. So `imgPicker` must be named `useImgPicker` - _"A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and that may call other Hooks."_ from https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Comment: @evolutionxbox , tnx I changed that do you have idea why i have this problem?

Comment: Where does `newUrl` come from in `someFunction`? It's never defined?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, the newUrl is created after some operation

Answer (score 0):

`diplayImg` method should use `useCallback` hook with dependency of `imgUrl`, I guess this will solve also the update of image source.

if not, consider splitting it into a new method that gets the view to render and wrapped that method with `memo` from `react` (React.memo) with the relevant dependency. (only the method that shows EmptyView vs the Image view)